# Excel VBA - Eliminate duplicates in a row

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

Good evening,

I have read through previous posts and cannot find an answer for this particular problem.

I have a VBA script in excel that returns values into A2,B2,C2 it then runs through a loop to populate data into A3,B3,C3 etc

What I need to do is eliminate the duplicate values in the row using VBA and return only the unique values. I am delimiting using the "/".

It needs to ignore any blank cells.

The idea is that the results are calculated before the next loop.

Ideally I would like to only display the result without having to populate A1,B1,C1 etc.

[image: Sample Data]

Your assistance in this is appreciated.

```
    'Conditions
  If Cells(rw, 24) = Cells(rw, 26) And Cells(rw, 24) = Cells(rw, 25) Then Cells(rw, 18) = "'" & Cells(rw, 24)
  If Cells(rw, 24) <> Cells(rw, 26) Then Cells(rw, 18) = Cells(rw, 24) & "/" & Cells(rw, 26)

  Cells(rw, 20) = Application.VLookup(Cells(rw, 18), Workbooks("CMF Export.xlsx").Sheets("Data").Columns("C:D"), 2, False) ' Vlookup function
  If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
 Cells(rw, 23 + i) = Right(aCell.Value, 7)
End If
```

Comment: Post what you have tried so far, that has failed.

Comment: I have used normal if statements as a formula to calculate the results. This is slowing down the entire process. I have no clue as to where to start with this particular problem.

Comment: This is code that I have tried but it does not take into consideration the third check. The cell referencing is not the same as my example but I will change to suite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [Collection](http://www.functionx.com/vbaexcel/objects/Lesson6.htm) to store unique values:

```
Sub test()
    Dim col As Collection
    Dim r As Range, c As Range
    Dim res As String, lastrow As Long, el
    'change sheet name to suit    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Find last non empty row in column A
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'add text format to column E
        .Range("E2:E" & lastrow).NumberFormat = "@"
        'iterates through each row
        For Each r In .Range("A2:C" & lastrow).Rows        
            'initialize collection
            Set col = New Collection
            'iterates through each cell in row
            For Each c In r.Cells
                'next lines adds only unique values
                On Error Resume Next
                col.Add CStr(c.Value), CStr(c.Value)
                On Error GoTo 0
            Next                
            'collect result
            res = ""
            For Each el In col
                res = res & el & "/"
            Next                              
            If res <> "" Then res = Left(res, Len(res) - 1)
            'write result in column E
            .Range("E" & r.Row).Value = res
            'adding VLOOKUP (follow up from comments)
            'With .Range("F" & r.Row)
            'adjust Sheet1!A1:C100 to suit your needs
            '    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & res & ",Sheet1!A1:C100,3,0)"
            'next line rewrites formula with formula result
            '    .Value = .Value
            'End With
            Set col = Nothing 
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. I will incorporate this into my scripting. I ran it across my example and it gave me the results I was looking for. :)

Comment: Now the fun part starts, trying to incorporate it into my code using the variables I have already created. lol

Comment: The script works like a dream thanks. Have incorporated it into my larger script. Where would I insert a Vlookup in your script if I want to use the results. Thanks,Mark

Comment: Sorry was not to sure how I could ask another question of you directly. I am a newby here.

Comment: So, clarify please why you need to use vlookup in script? you could use formula in any cell: `=VLOOKUP("1/2",E2:F100,2,0)` to get value from, say, column `F` where corresponding value in column `E` is `"1/2"`

Comment: I am working through huge amounts of data on a daily basis. I have automated all the processes so far. What I use the lookup for is to bring back a product description based on the results that your script has provided. I want to keep human intervention out of the mix as much as possible. It would be easier to have it automated, in that way I will not have to write the vlookup formula for each workbook I work with. Which can range into the 50's on a daily basis.

Comment: Let you want to get some value in col `F` based on value from col E, then add `.Range("F" & r.Row).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & res & ",Sheet1!A1:C100,3,0)"` before line `Set col = Nothing`. If you don't wnat to leave formula in your cell (you want to leave just value), also add this line: `.Range("F" & r.Row).Value = .Range("F" & r.Row).Value`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48000/discussion-between-mark-and-simoco)